# Passing database name to sql statement as parameter with pymysql

Tags: python, pymysql

I would like to pass database as parameter

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM %s.table1'
values = 'db-1'

cursor.execute(sql, values)
```

The problem is that `%s` is escaped using single quotes and it generates an error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near ''qualys_scan'.new_table' at line 1

On the other hand, using a simple parameter replacement:

> 'SELECT * FROM %s.table1'.format(values)

is exploitable by sql injection.

Any suggestion how to handle this?
Approach for different mysql modules will be also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

SQL injections are only a problem if the values (in this case the db name) come from an untrusted source, and even then you could sanitize the db name manually.

This being said, it might be easier to pass the db name to the `connection` object - eventually keeping a map of db_name:connection to avoid reopening new connections each time.

Comment: currently i am using _USE db_name;_ sql statement when cursor is created, it is ok but soon there can be joins across different databases so i wanted to implement some general secure mechanism to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

PyMySQL currently offers no means of performing input validation for database or table names.

A possible solution to prevent SQL Injection with database/table names is to validate the input containing the database/table name, according to a list of possible database/table names.

For example:

```
permitted_databases = ['db-1', 'db-2', 'db-3']
user_input_database_name = 'db-1' # This would come from, for example, a user HTTP request, but here it's hardcoded for simplicity

if user_input_database_name not in permitted_databases:
    print("This database does not exist")
else:
    sql = f'SELECT * FROM {user_input_database_name}.table1'
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

This solution was proposed [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37331403/4212870)

However, **beware** of opening your application to other vulnerabilities when doing so. For example, [Broken Access Control](https://owasp.org/Top10/A01_2021-Broken_Access_Control/) was the number one vulnerability on OWASP 2021, and [BOLA](https://owasp.org/API-Security/editions/2023/en/0xa1-broken-object-level-authorization/) is the number one in 2023. If a user should not have access to a specific database, then other control mechanisms should be implemented as well.

Answer (score -2):

You could do something like below

```
values = 'db-1'

sql = 'SELECT * from {val}.table1'.format(val=values)
print(sql) # 'SELECT * from db-1.table1'
```

then you can do `conn.execute(sql)`

another example for multiple params:

```
query_string = 'SELECT * from {tablename} WHERE DATE(End_time) = "{date}"'.format(tablename=table,date=date)
```

in your case:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM {database}.table1'
values = 'db-1'
cursor.execute(sql.format(database=values))
```

Comment: Congratulations, all script-kiddies will be very happy to play havoc with your database. http://bobby-tables.com/ anyone ?

Comment: @Chandu , your answer will not prevent SQL Injection, which is what the OP is worried about.